# serialize nested objects using class-transformer : Nest js

Tags: typescript, nestjs, class-transformer

I am trying to serialize nested objects using a class transformer. I have two dtos like below. When I am trying to serialize using `plainToClass` the nested object gets removed from the output. only getting the parent object's data.

**User dto:**

```
export class UserDto extends AbstractDto {
    @Expose()
    email: string;

    @Expose()
    first_name: string;

    @Expose()
    last_name: string;

    @Expose()
    profile: ProfileDto

}
```

**Profile dto:**

```
export class ProfileDto extends AbstractDto {
    @Expose()
    date_of_birth: string;

    @Expose()
    address: string;

    @Expose()
    pincode: string;
}
```

**Serializer:**

```
const serialized = plainToClass(UserDto, user, {
    excludeExtraneousValues: true,
});
```

**Expected Output:**

```
{
    email:'a@gmail.com',
    first_name: 'test',
    last_name: 'test',
    profile: {
        date_of_birth: '',
        address: '',
        pincode: ''
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have found the answer here [Link](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer/issues/876). If I add `enableImplicitConversion: true` along with the `@Type` decorator then it is working as expected.

```
export class UserDto extends AbstractDto {
    @Expose()
    email: string;

    @Expose()
    first_name: string;

    @Expose()
    last_name: string;

    @Expose()
    @Type(() => ProfileDto)
    profile: ProfileDto

}
```

Serializer:

```
const serialized = plainToClass(UserDto, user, {
    excludeExtraneousValues: true,
    enableImplicitConversion: true
    
});
```

Comment: If you're using `class-transformer` and `class-validator` together then you usually **do not** want to enable implicit conversion according to the docs https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer#implicit-type-conversion

Issue is things like `myField: string` will pretty much always pass validation as almost everything can be converted to a string, including objects etc.

Comment: @TomManterfield I just ran into what you're referring to. Booleans will always be true even when set to strings. Do you have an alternative option for nested serialization?

Answer (score 2):

This question is not related to [NestJS](https://nestjs.com/), but purely to [class-transformer](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer#classtoplain). NestJS might happen to use the `class-validator` & `class-transformer` packages as part of its [pipes](https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes) feature, but in the context of this question NestJS doesn't even need to be considered.

Let's assume you have two classes, `Cat` and `Owner`. An owner can have a cat.

```
class Cat {
  @Expose()
  name: string;

  @Expose()
  age: number;

  favoriteFood: string;

  constructor(name: string, age: number, favoriteFood: string) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.favoriteFood = favoriteFood;
  }
}

class Owner {
  @Expose()
  name: string;

  @Expose()
  cat: Cat;

  constructor(name: string, cat: Cat) {
    this.name = name;
    this.cat = cat;
  }
}
```

Let's instantiate an instance of each.

```
const cat = new Cat('Misty', 6, 'Dry cat food');
const owner = new Owner('Christophe', cat);
```

If you want to convert the owner instance back into a plain JavaScript object then use the `instanceToPlain()` function with the `excludeAll` strategy from `class-transformer`. The `classToPlain()` function is deprecated.

```
const serialized = instanceToPlain(owner, { strategy: 'excludeAll' });
```

That will only serialize the properties you decorated with the `@Expose()` decorator:

`{ name: 'Christophe', cat: { name: 'Misty', age: 6 } }`

The `plainToClass()` you used in your example is meant to convert a plain JavaScript back into an instance of the `Owner` class, or for "deserializing" rather.

For more information consult the `class-transformer` documentation.

https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer